# How to make two rows to have the same ending and starting point?

Tags: html, css

I want to make cal and email to have same starting and ending point means ending and starting should be aligned for all screens. How to do that?

```
 <span style="text-align: center;font-family:Myriad Pro;font-weight:bold">
 Call :- <span class="word">91</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="word">number</span><br>
 + <span class="word">91</span><span class="word">number</span><br>
 Email :- care@
```

[image]

Comment: Is the image above your current output, or your desired output?  Could you also include whichever of these be missing?

Comment: its the current output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your content in a table, it will make your content neater.

For example :

```
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>Call</td>
         <td>
             Number One<br>
             Number Two
         </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
         <td>E-mail</td>
         <td>email@email.com</td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

You can see my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/865u48y3/). Or you can check this link for more example [W3School Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: number one and number two should start and end with email@email.com

Comment: Can you post a image of result what do you want? Please more specific question.

Comment: What is your mean you want the result like justify effect?

Answer (score 0):

try using `<table>,<tr> and <td>`, would make it more structural..

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Call </td>
<td>:</td>
<td> +Number</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp</td>
<td> +Number </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>blank@email.com</td>
</tr>

</table>
```